# Finitely-Generated modules over a commutative ring with $1$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Suppose that every module $M$ over $A$ is finitely.generated with rank $n$ and every submodule $N \leq M$ has rank $r \leq n$. Show $A$ is a principal ideal domain. I do not how having a finite base is related to being a module over a commutative ring with $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The premise "Suppose that every module $M$ over $A$ is finitely generated..." doesn't make sense since you can't demand all modules are finitely generated: consider $M = \bigoplus_{n \geq 1} A$, which is not finitely generated (except for the silly case where $A$ is the zero ring).

What you meant to say is "Suppose every module $M$ over $A$ that is finitely generated...". In other words, it is an assumption on all finitely generated $A$-modules, not on all $A$-modules.  And when you say "... every submodule $N \subset M$ has rank $r \leq n$" did you mean "... every submodule $N \subset M$ is free of rank $r \leq n$"?

If you are assuming every finitely generated $A$-module is free and their submodules are also free of rank no greater than the rank of the starting module, then just look at the *example* of the $A$-module $A$ itself (free of rank $1$), whose submodules are its ideals to deduce that (i) all ideals are principal and (ii) $A$ is an integral domain.

Comment: That is a (very useful) comment, but not an answer.

Comment: @RobArthan I edited the end of my answer. While I am not giving a full answer to the question, I am directing the OP to the only cases worth thinking about among all $A$-modules. And I think that qualifies as a reasonable answer, as the OP can now think about the relevant situation.

Comment: What means "OP"?

Comment: @Student2271 that is *you*: OP = original poster or original post.